# Callback to be run at the end of the job

Tags: luatex, callback

My Lua initialization script opens some files that are written to in the course of the run. I would like to additionally write some last bytes to them when LuaTeX is done processing all code.

It seems this would be best accomplished with a callback, but I haven't found any that fully suits my needs:

- `stop_run` (§ 7.1.5.3) works, but:

  - isn't run in draft mode (`--draftmode`);
  - replaces the default end-of-job message, which I would prefer to avoid doing;
  - seems meant for information reporting, despite its tempting name.
- `finish_pdffile` (§ 7.1.6.1) works, but:

  - isn't run in draft mode either;
  - works only with the PDF output. I would very much prefer an output-agnostic solution.

See the current version of the [LuaTeX manual](http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatex.pdf) for a more detailed description of those callbacks.

`\AtEndDocument` is not suitable because:

- the files can still be written to after `\end{document}`.
- TeX code can't be processed yet at the time of the Lua initialization script (i.e. `tex.sprint` and friends aren't available). While I could hook into another callback to do a `tex.sprint( appropiate_catcode_table , [[\AtEndDocument{ \directlua{ work() } }]] )`, this seems overly indirect.

Could you please help me?

Comment: There's no reasonable way to process the dvi files created by LuaTeX, right? I'm not sure if the output-agnostic requirement is all that necessary. But not running in draft mode is more likely a feature not a bug for that, so doesn't help in this case :)